# Migration from Struts 1 and Apache Axis1 based application to Struts 2, (CXF or Jersey) based application

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, struts2, jersey, cxf

We have an application It is built on following:
BachEnd:

1. Struts 1
2. Apache Axis 1 (SOAP based)

Front End:

1. HTML
2. Flash(Some grids are built on Adobe flex 3)
3. Dojo

We are migrating to struts 2,apache CXF or Jersey (for Rest web serv.) for backend and (HTML5,Jquery and JQWidget) for frontend.

Please suggest a rough idea what should be done first:

1. Apache axis1 to CXF or Jersey (Also tell what should be used between
   these two)
2. Struts 1 to Struts 2
3. Change Front end things first.

We can not migrate all at once, We have to move step by step one change then another so after each technology change the application should be useable, Still I am looking into the architecture of application but any one experience such migration then please suggest.What should be done first?

Comment: yar tum sab reviewer bhar mai jao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not about what to migrate first but the real question is why are you migrating?
I can understand replacing flash in the front end but for the others you must have good reasons.
For example you are talking about migrating SOAP to REST is it for some good reason? Cause it not the same notion. The same thing about struts 1 and struts 2 the common thing between them is the name "struts" but it's again not the same notion behind, is it for security vulnerability? If it is true have you looked for a solution with the same technology? ...

I am not trying to criticize but the most important thing is that you must know exactly the reasons behind changing technology/notion by another cause the cost of migration is very important with high risk.

**At last I think building a new application will be simpler, safer and cheaper than migration**

Good Luck

Comment: Ofcourse performance and these technologies is obsolete, we need to replace it with the latest technologies in order to compete with market other products and also the user attention so they can continue using our product.(I am not forgetting new feature as well, Will be introduced in it).

Comment: Code management is also difficult with current architecture that is why we are revamping and introducing new technologies.

Comment: in this case I’ll prefer building a new one so I can improve my architecture, feature and all things that was difficult to maintain, extend, improve, or integrate... otherwise I think with all the old background and history you will be facing a problem like "we don't know why we have this code/feature here” or “why is it done this way” moreover “how can we do it with the new framework” ... rather than concentrating on the functionality

Comment: In the other hand consider improving user experience because they will not see how good your architecture is but just how the new version will make their work easier and simpler with good looking GUIs
At last talking is very easy than doing thing so good luck :)